# How to calculate rank within Sales ranges

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to calculate rank within Category defined on sales level. Say, that we want to label products with Sales above some threshold with Category "high", and below that threshold with Category "low".

Here is a sample data.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcisqzSwpVtJRSiwoyEkF0oZKsTpIwkmJeUAIZJigipfn56QlpRYVVQLZpqhSyRlQcWOweFhqempJYlJOKlgusagovwS7XEF+SWJJPtwJKHL5eZn5eUDaHNUqHI5GdkEsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, Product = _t, Amount = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Amount", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

My question is a nephew related to [its older uncle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102487/1903793), who now I want to call in:

```
Percent Rank within Category = 

VAR HasOneValueTrue = HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] )

VAR tbl =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( MyTable[Product] ),          
        REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[Product] ),   
        VALUES ( MyTable[Category] )          
    )

VAR result =
    CALCULATE (
        DIVIDE (
            RANKX (
                tbl,
                [Sales], 
                ,
                ASC
            ) - 1,
            COUNTROWS ( tbl ) - 1
        )
    )
RETURN 
    IF (
        HasOneValueTrue,
        result
    )
```

The difference is that the uncle has Category defined in table column, but now we want to have category calculated on the fly based on sales level. So I tried 
replacing the `VAR tbl` code with the following one with the threshold of 4:

```
var tbl =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    MyTable[Product],
    "CalculatedCategory", IF ( [Sales] > 4, "high", "low" ),
    "AggSales", [Sales]
)
```

Nevertheless, I am not able to refer to such defined variable. I also failed with trial based on creating first a DAX table and then trying to refer to it.

Here are expected results:

[image: expected results]

**References**

Here is the family of related questions which members I met on the way while approaching to state this problem.

[DAX equivalent of Excel PERCENTRANK.INC per category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102487/1903793)

[DAX RANKX for within Category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102931/1903793)

[DAX REMOVEFILTERS vs ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59191631/1903793)

[The value parameter in DAX function RANKX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59093139/1903793)

[DAX ALLEXCEPT to sum by category of multiple dimension tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58978358/1903793)

Comment: Can you show what you want your result to look like?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Expected results is served!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being very grateful to Alexis Olson, I would like to share a different solution I ended up with. The solution proposed by Alexis works well in my simple example, but it did not work in my complex model. In my complex model the RANKX function does not give the expected results. RANKX returns the same rankings for different sales values.

For the time being this is the solution that works without figuring out what causes RANKX to return ties for different sales values.

First of all, defining Category measure:

```
CalculatedCategory = 
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    NOT ( HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] ) ), "total", -- important to handle totals
    [Sales] <= 4, "low",
    [Sales] >  4, "high",
    "other"
)
```

It is important to exclude totals from Category. I did it by setting up a different category for totals. Otherwise totals will fall into "high" category bucket. It would distort final results.

I have not used RANKX in calculation of Percent Rank within Category. I used MIXTURE OF COUNTROWS and FILTER.

```
PercentRank within Category = 
VAR category = [CalculatedCategory]
VAR ProductSales = [Sales]
VAR ProductsMatching = 
COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] ),
                [CalculatedCategory] = category
                    && [Sales] >= ProductSales
            )
        )
var ProductsAll = 
COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] ),
                [CalculatedCategory] = category
            )
        )

RETURN
    DIVIDE (ProductsMatching-1, MAX( ProductsAll-1, 1 ))
```

I calculated rows of two tables. First table `ProductsMatching` has all products that have sales in appropriate category and sales that are higher or equal of the product. `ProductsAll` returns number of products in category.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a minor modification to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102487/dax-equivalent-of-excel-percentrank-inc-per-category/59202967#59202967). Copied below:

```
Percent Rank =
VAR ProductsInCategory =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( MyTable[Product] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] )
    )
VAR RankProduct = RANKX ( ProductsInCategory, [Sales],, ASC )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] ),
        DIVIDE ( RankProduct - 1, COUNTROWS ( ProductsInCategory ) - 1 )
    )
```

First, define the calculated category as you suggested.

```
CalculatedCategory = IF ( [Sales] > 4, "high", "low" )
```

Then plug that into a filter in the `ProductsInCategory` variable.

```
Exp. Results =
VAR CalculatedCategory = [CalculatedCategory] /*Determine current category*/
VAR ProductsInCategory =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( MyTable[Product] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] ),
            [CalculatedCategory] = CalculatedCategory /*New Condition*/
        )
    )
VAR RankProduct = RANKX ( ProductsInCategory, [Sales],, ASC )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] ),
        DIVIDE ( RankProduct - 1, COUNTROWS ( ProductsInCategory ) - 1 )
    )
```

Output:

[image: Matrix Visual]

---

**Edit:**

To handle the case where there is only 1 product in a category, you can use `MAX` to disallow a zero value for the denominator.

```
Exp. Results =
VAR CalculatedCategory = [CalculatedCategory] /*Determine current category*/
VAR ProductsInCategory =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( MyTable[Product] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] ),
            [CalculatedCategory] = CalculatedCategory /*New Condition*/
        )
    )
VAR RankProduct = RANKX ( ProductsInCategory, [Sales],, ASC )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] ),
        DIVIDE (
            RankProduct - 1,
            MAX ( COUNTROWS( ProductsInCategory ) - 1, 1 )
        )
    )
```

Comment: I have not thought about it so far. What if CalculatedCategory has only one product? Then Exp. Results is blank. Definitely it should not. I would be satisfied if it was either 0% or 100% but definitely not a blank Excel equivalent function shows 100% for one cell array. My only preference between 0% or 100% is readability of code. The simpler the better.

Comment: Alexis, it is pleasure to grant you bounty. I had no luck with RANKX. I keep receiving ranking ties for different sales. I will try to cook an example which replicates that behavior. I shared a solution which overcomes that problem. I would not be able to achieve it without your answer. Thank you.